# Perform a GroupJoin using Linq based on function

Tags: c#, linq

Firstly, I was looking for some advice on how to perform a group join based on function rather than the equality of two keys.

Secondly, in my actual application Resources (an array of strings) are loaded from a file. I dont want to load these each time I enumerate the sequence. I was hoping to create a function that would allow deferred execution.

```
var files = new[]
{
    new { Name = "A", Resources = new[] { "A.1", "A.2" } }, 
    new { Name = "B", Resources = new[] { "B.1", "B.2" } }
};

var resources = new[] 
{ 
    new { File = "A", Resources = new[] {"C", "D"} },
    new { File = "B", Resources = new[] {"E", "F"} },
    new { File = "A.1", Resources = new[] {"C.1", "D.1"} },
    new { File = "A.2", Resources = new[] {"C.2", "D.2"} },
    new { File = "B.1", Resources = new[] {"E.1", "F.1"} },
    new { File = "B.2", Resources = new[] {"E.2", "F.2"} },
};

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File {0}", file.Name);

    var fileResources = resources.Where(r => r.File == file.Name).SelectMany(r => r.Resources);                    
    var childResources = file.Resources.SelectMany(c => resources.Where(r => r.File == c).SelectMany(r => r.Resources));

    // How can we perform a group join using c.StartsWith(t)
    var groupedResources = fileResources.GroupJoin(childResources, t => t, c => c, (p, c) => new { Parent = p, Children = c });
    foreach (var grouping in groupedResources)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", grouping.Parent);
        foreach (var child in grouping.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", child);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output would be

```
File A
C
    C.1
    C.2
D
    D.1
    D.2
File B
E
    E.1
    E.2
F
    F.1
    F.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [group clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) instead of `GropJoin` something like this

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var groupedResources = from r in resources
                           join f in file.Resources on r.File equals f
                           from childResource in r.Resources

                           from fileResource in resources
                           from parentResource in fileResource.Resources
                           where fileResource.File == file.Name

                           group childResource by new { parentResource, IsStart = childResource.StartsWith(parentResource) } into g
                           where g.Key.IsStart
                           select new { Parent = g.Key.parentResource, Children = g };

    foreach (var grouping in groupedResources)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", grouping.Parent);
        foreach (var child in grouping.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", child);
        }
    }
}
```